# How to configure modulePath for an unmanaged folder in VSCODE

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, module, unmanaged

I want to move away from Maven builds.

I have a module-info.java that is correctly resolved when the required modular JARs are stated as dependencies in the POM, that is, when using maven with vscode. When I remove the POM the "requires" in module-info.java goes red "... cannot be resolved to a module".

`module-info.jar`

```
module net.kwami.utils {
    requires transitive org.apache.logging.log4j;
    requires transitive com.google.gson;
    requires transitive org.yaml.snakeyaml;
    exports net.kwami.utils;
}
```

Compiling from the command-line works:

```
bin$ javac -d ../target --module-path ../lib $(find ../src/main -name "*.java")
bin$
```

The Referenced Libraries tab in vscode automatically shows the modular JARs because I have them in tne lib directory of the folder.

I tried to add --module-path to the vmargs of the Redhat Language Server. I tried to add modulePath to the runtime configuration but that is not allowed and intellisense does not offer it.

I expected the language server to detect the module descriptor and use the configured Referenced Libraries as the --module-path used by the compiler.

Comment: Do you want to customize the execution command of java script?

Comment: @JialeDu, I think I need to configure the Eclipse compiler to use a --module-path

Comment: Sorry for not understanding your question. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)